# What is the everyday term for "a piece of dried mucus from the corners of your eyes, which we often have in the early morning after getting up"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

It seems that "[Rheum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheum)" is the technical word to express

> a thin mucus naturally discharged from the eyes, nose, or mouth, often
> during sleep (cf. mucopurulent discharge)
>
> Dried rheum is commonly called sleep,[4] sleepy-seeds,[5] sleepy
> buds,[5] sleepy sand, sleepies, eye boogers, eye crust, eye goop,
> sleep dust, [6] or sleepy dirt.

Among those words, **which one is the one we often say in everyday conversation?**

Comment: Impossible to answer.  You quoted six right there.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, too many words. I just want to know which is the most popular

Comment: Most popular where? According to whom?

Comment: I made an error. You quoted ten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose any of those.  If you want someone to pick one for you, pick the first one: "sleep".

> He yawned and rubbed the sleep out his eyes. Blinking, he looked around the room. Yes, the penguin was still there....

Comment: I found that noun in the dictionary.so it is ok to use.